# Ajustar elementos automáticamente al contenedor (centrado, espaciado, etc.) en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

Existe la posibilidad de centrar botones dentro de un `<div>`, que todos tengan el mismo tamaño, se muestren en una sola línea (uno al lado del otro) y queden espaciados igualmente de manera automática, sin tener que setear uno mismo los valores de los anchos y altos, los margin, etc ? Es decir, lo que deseo es que se ajuste automáticamente al contenedor. Un código simplificado de lo que estoy intentando hacer es:

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
#container2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background: steelblue;
  float: left;
}
#container3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: burlywood;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container2"></div>
  <div id="container3">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>AB</button>
    <button>ABC</button>
    <button>C</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como se puede observar en las líneas anteriores, hay textos mas largos que otros. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tu `div` que tiene el id `#container3` y que sirve de padre para los 4 botones, aplicale estas propiedades de *flexbox*

```
#container3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: burlywood;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

- `display: flex;` para hacer a sus elementos internos flexibles
- `justify-content: space-between;` aplica un espaciado entre los elementos de igual tamaño o pudieras aplicar `space-around` que aparte del espacio entre los elementos, también colocará un espacio a los elementos primero y último con respecto de su contenedor, tanto del lado izquierdo y del lado derecho
- `align-items` para centrar verticalmente los botones
- Quita la propiedad `float: left;`

Revisa este snippet

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
#container2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background: steelblue;
  float: left;
}
#container3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: burlywood;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container2"></div>
  <div id="container3">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>AB</button>
    <button>ABC</button>
    <button>C</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edición**

- Puedes prescindir de la línea `align-items: center;` para no alinear verticalmente
- a los botones les agregas una altura con la siguiente regla:

Código

```
#container3 > button{
    height: 10%;
}
```

De modo que con lo anterior quedan alineados a la parte superior solamente.

Gracias FRANCISCO J. BLANCO por la pista

Comment: Creo que para que los botones tengan el mismo tamaño tienes que agregar esto `#container3 > button {
  width: 15%;
}` en el **css**

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo !